# Use attribute conditional inside sort_by to catch nil values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following line to calculate how many days a player has been at a club:

```
Player.where(:current_player => false).sort_by {|p| p.departures.first.departure_date - p.arrivals.first.arrival_date}
```

This works fine for non-current players. However, I want to include not only former players, but also current ones. I want to exchange `Player.where(:current_player => false)` with `Player.all`, but then the `sort_by` obviously catches a bunch of nulls (because current players have no departures - they're still at the club).

I then tried this conditional:

```
Player.all.sort_by {|p| (p.departures.first.departure_date || Date.today) - p.arrivals.first.arrival_date}
```

...but I realised that the reason it still fails is because it's looking for a `departure_date` on a nil object (because `p.departures` doesn't exist on all players).

**So ideally I need *something like this*, but I can't get it to work:**

```
Player.all.sort_by {|p| (IF p.departures? p.departures.first.departure_date ELSE Date.today) - p.arrivals.first.arrival_date}
```

I know it's wrong, just showing what I'm trying to achieve:

1. If player has any departures, use `p.departures.first.departure_date`
2. Else use `Date.today`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `Player` will have a collection of `departures`, however that collection may be empty so `p.departures.first` is going to return `nil`.

You could use rails `try` method in this case

```
Player.all.sort_by {|p| (p.departures.first.try(:departure_date) || Date.today) - p.arrivals.first.arrival_date}
```

It is a handy method but when used a lot often implies there is something smelly with the code.

ALSO: you will usually want to use `Date.current` instead of `Date.today` as current is time zone aware